# Sources from two SVN repos

Tags: svn

I have a java project checked out from one SVN repository where I have read access.
To this project I added my own package.
I have uploaded the entire project, including my package to my own SVN repository.
Is there an easy way to update my sources from the repository where I initially got the project?

Answer (score 4):

This situation is usually handled using [Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

**EDIT**

Also consider using a distributed version control system ([Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/), [Git](http://git-scm.com/)). I think most of them can also connect to subversion repositories (for Bazaar I'm sure ...) and they are specifically designed for such situations.

Comment: I read about those but the bad part is that my folder is somewhere deep in the folder tree. I would have to copy each of the folders manually, right?

Comment: Basically you have one branch for the original library. You make an initial copy from this branch to your trunk and keep working there. If there are changes in the original library, you put these changes in the vendor branch (manually afaik) and then merge these changes back into the trunk. It makes no big difference where your changes are located, the principle is always the same.

Comment: OK, I think I will try that. It would be nice to be able to just integrate them though.

I want to stick to svn since I have a repository for it. (I am not the server admin)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for SVN externals: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Comment: I see, then yeah, you want vendor branches. My answer is wrong.